# Selecting row with highest value based on two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:
I want to make a rule that if for a same city and same id, pick the maximum value and drop the row with lower value.

eg:

| City | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | 1 | 12.45 |
| Amsterdam | 1 | 14.56 |
| Paris | 1 | 16.89 |
| New York | 1 | 23.86 |
| Chicago | 1 | 14.56 |
| Chicago | 1 | 20.76 |

Expected Output : Select highest value for same city and ID.
Here Chicago has 2 entries with same ID, I want to select the row with highest value.

Expected Output

| City | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | 1 | 12.45 |
| Amsterdam | 1 | 14.56 |
| Paris | 1 | 16.89 |
| New York | 1 | 23.86 |
| Chicago | 1 | 20.76 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the dataframe by Value in descending order and drop the duplicates:

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=['Value'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['City', 'ID'], keep='first')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        City  ID  Value
3   New York   1  23.86
5    Chicago   1  20.76
2      Paris   1  16.89
1  Amsterdam   1  14.56
0     London   1  12.45
```